# Is there a way to get the both main stream and sub stream together in opencv python

Tags: python, video-capture, ip-camera, opencv

I am using **DAHUA Thermal Camera**

Camera can provide two streams **(Color_Stream + Thermal_Stream)**.

I am getting the color stream from my thermal camera in python through the given URL with `cv2.VideoCapture()` function (keeping **channel=1** in the URL)

> rtsp://admin:admin@10.7.6.67:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0

and thermal stream with the given URL (keeping **channel=2** in the URL)

> rtsp://admin:admin@10.7.6.67:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2&subtype=0

Is there a way that I can get both of the streams together? (by calling only one function)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this with an IP camera. But perhaps what you can try is using 2 threads to open the 2 streams. Then you may be able to fetch both streams. If that does not work, you can try switching between streams alternately, if it helps

Comment: Yeah That's the ultimate solution which is I am using right now.

But I just wanted to see if there's any way to pick them both together maybe through rtsp link or so.

Thanks for the answer by the way :)